# Can we forward the email with email images in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to forward email through apps script. My code is.

```
  var message = getCurrentMessage(event);
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  var msg= message.getPlainBody();
  MailApp.sendEmail(txt_input,subject,msg);
```

Code worked perfect but issue is that if i want to forward email which contains images then it's not send images. 
Note that i am not talking about attachments.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly forward the email using [`GmailMessage.forward`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object))

```
message.forward("recipient@example.com,recipient1@example.com");
```

Comment: Yes it's worked, but i am want to send email without header. Mean that i want just remove the forwarded mail header.